# Audio which is recorded in iOS programmatically could not be playable in Windows

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, audio-recording

**Scenario:** The App which I am working on I am suppose to recored voice memos and send them to the Windows client. Recording audio in iOS is not that much hard but the recorded file (in my case in the form of .mp3) `could not be playable in Windows` but the same file `could be easily playable in Mac`.

I strongly suspect on my audio recording settings which I am using in the following code,

```
_audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:audioFileURL settings:_recordingSettings error:&error];
```

and the settings that I am using is,

```
_recordingSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                      nil];
```

I have already tried the various `AVFormatIDKey`s such as

```
kAudioFormatLinearPCM    - .lpcm
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC     - .acc
kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3   - .mp3
```

but no gain.

I appreciate any help. In case if it is not possible I need the explanation why!

Comment: export it as linear PCM and then just adjust the header to wav? https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, but the solution is little bit complicated. I have managed my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some random tries I have managed myself with the settings,

```
_recordingSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                     nil];
```

**Important:** The filename should be **"someName.wav"**